# Injected service keeps throwing NullPointerException

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, jboss7.x, java-ee-6, cdi

When accessing the injected service as below `test()` throws a `NullPointerException`.
If I do not inject but use a new instance of `BugService` the `NPE` will be thrown at next step: `BugService`'s `getItems()`.
Actually I find it really hard to understand the JEE6-Tutorial's Section on CDI, so I guess I am missing something quite basic. Appreciate your help.

This is the Java Class:

```
package hoho.misc;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import hoho.service.BugService;

@Named
public class Printer implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    BugService bs;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Printer lPrinter = new Printer();
        System.out.println(lPrinter.test());
    }

    public String test(){
        String result = bs.getItems().toString();
        return result;
    }
}
```

And the injected service:

```
package hoho.service;

import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;
import hoho.model.generated.Item;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class ItemService
 */
@Stateless
public class BugService {

   /**
    * Default constructor.
    */
   public BugService() {
   }

   @PersistenceContext
   EntityManager em;

   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   public List<Item> getItems() {
      return this.em.createQuery(
              "SELECT i FROM Item i")
              .getResultList();
   }   
}
```

my jboss-deployment-structure.xml

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
  <deployment>
    <exclusions>
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-atom-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-cdi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxb-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jsapi" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-multipart-provider" />
      <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.async-http-servlet-30" />
      <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
    </exclusions>
  </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>

<!-- 
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.0">
        <deployment>
                 <exclusions>
                        <module name="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
                 </exclusions>
        </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
 -->
```

this is my beans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/beans_1_0.xsd">

</beans>
```

Comment: The EJB won't work if you instantiate it by hand, because at that point, it's no longer a managed object but a POJO. Do you have *ejb-jar.xml* packaged in the *META-INF* directory of the EJB jar file? Also what App server are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, I do not have a `ejb-jar.xml` at all, isn't that one optional for EJB 3.1? (oh **** I missed the java-ee6 tag - sorry!) I am using JBoss AS 7.1.1.

Comment: How about beans.xml? What is your deployment structure?

Comment: @LightGuard I added the requested files. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, I meant war or ear? Also where are your bean.xml files?

Comment: @LightGuard I'm using war. my `beans.xml` is inside `/WebContent/WEB-INF`.

Answer (score 2):

Unless something is radically different in JBOSS compared to to the java-ee container i worked with (glassfish), you shouldnt try to access the bean using a homemade main-method (as the container will not be in play).

One option is to bind the named bean to some jsf-page and invoke the test() with a button perhaps.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton action="#{printer.test}" value="Add"/>
</h:form>
```

I like [this tutorial on jsf-cdi-ejb](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/jsf-cdi-and-ejb/)

Comment: Ah, I think you hit it Aksel, I missed it. CDI is a container managed technology. You can't use `new` and expect everything to be wired up for you.

Comment: @Aksel Thank you for your answer. Your way I get the `NPE` at the line of `BugService` where the code is `return this.em.createQuery(`.
I will look into the named tutorial and give some feedback, how it helped/not helped with my problem.

Comment: that means injection of the EntityManager did not take place. Perhaps there is something in the server-log when you deploy?